# Saving results from Execute SQL Task to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to develop a package in SSIS. The package's logic is relatively simple: Execute a Query and save the result set in an excel spreadsheet. Hence I first tried to create an architecture as shown below:- 
             [image]
  
 The problem I'm facing is that the query makes use of temporary tables and OLE DB Source doesn't seem to be able to parse queries containing temp tables(#table-names).

So i tried using a Execute SQL task in my control flow. This seems to be able to execute this query. But now I want to obtain the entire result set and save that in an Excel spreadsheet that is named dynamically. 
 I understand creating a temp table is a solution, but I cannot use that as the client wont be happy about it.
  I've tried saving the result set in a variable but even that I cannot read from the OLEDB Source. 
  Can anyone please give me suggestions on this. If u want any clarifications, do  comment.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use a staging table?  Instead of creating a temp table, truncate the staging table.  Everything else should be the same.

Comment: @Dan-> No pal :(. Not allowed to create any DB Object on the server

Comment: Can you get the dba to do it for you?

Comment: Use **Execute SQL Task** to create temp table with result set . Create a variable which will hold the result set. Use **Retainsameconnection** Property. In **OLEDB Source** consider variable as a input which actually is a output of the **Execute SQL Task**.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite -> Yes your correct that approach works

Answer (score 0):

I would move the temporary table logic to a Common Table Expression (CTE), e.g.

```
WITH CTE_temp AS (
<< select statement that populates your temporary table >>
)
SELECT
<< select statement from your temporary table>>
FROM CTE_temp
```

CTEs can be built ontop of other CTEs, and can be recursive.  With some lateral thinking they cover 99.9% of temporary table solutions.

CTEs can run in parallel without contention issues.  They are usually faster than temp table solutions also.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using “RetainSameConnection” property of the connection manager defined.
(when you cretae the temp var the temp var is delete when the connection is closed...)