# Creating XLS file from Stored Procedure using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I put the stored procedure in a `Execute SQL` task and store the multi row results in an Object Variable.

Now I want to export that collection to a Excel file. Do I need to create a DATA FLOW to do this instead of a Foreach container?

I am very new to SSIS so I hope this should not be that complex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a Data Flow Task.  I think what you would want is an oledb source and an excel destination inside your Data Flow Task.  You shouldnt need the For Each task or the Execute SQL Task.  Change the Data Access for the OleDb Source to "SQL command" and give it the sql command for calling your stored proc.

Comment: I tried that other way and had issues (see link) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729992/saving-results-from-execute-sql-task-to-excel

Comment: So a Execute SQL Task object seems to have no problem calling a SP that makes temp tables so I went that direction. At least I got to the point where I can iterate through each row .. So if can do that maybe I can somehow append the rows to a XLS file or something ?

Comment: In the other post, it sounds like you were directly executing the the sql with the #temp table in it.  In this one you have a stored proc that you are calling.  What happens if you call the stored proc in the source?  Or have you tried calling the stored proc and I misunderstood what the other post was saying?

Comment: e.g. `Exec proc_GetMyData` vs. `select * into #tempTable; Select * from #tempTable`

Comment: The SP contains creating a temp table.. I found some posts on retaining the connection and somehow accessing the table .. but I still was not clear on how to get that OBJECT that contained a table set to a excel destination which was in the data flow.. while the SQL task was in control flow.. So I gave up and tell my boss I can just do it all in code.. though I am sad because if I had a resource to teach me some basic things I'm sure this is easy to do